# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt'

Tags: php, mcrypt

I am running

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1288]
Wamp 3.2.2.2 64bits
PHP 7.4.0
Composer version 2.1.12
Laravel Installer 4.2.9
```

When I tried running `php artisan serve` I got an error **Mcrypt PHP extension required**, okay I googled this problem, found some tutorials to add `php_mcrypt.dll` file to my `php7.4.0/ext` folder, okay I downloaded it, added it to the folder, added it to the `php.ini` file, restarted WAMP and tried running `php artisan serve` again, this time I am getting

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.0/ext/mcrypt (The specified module could not be found.), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.0/ext/php_mcrypt.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Could somebody please help me? I have searched all of google and youtube for solution but nothing works

Comment: Mcrypt is gone (old, not supported for ages) So i guess whatever you are trying to use is also old and could be considered out of date

Comment: Where did you get the mcrypt.dll file from

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just started a new laravel project, I am not using anything old, why does it want me to use mcrypt then?

Comment: SO you are installing Laravel 8?